# Is this the way to check function available on react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Today i see this code on my current project, a little confuse

```
 {rating && (
              <View style={rateFunction ? [ratingCont, { justifyContent: "space-between" }] : ratingCont}>
                {this.star &&
                  this.star.map((rate, index) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      key={index}
                      style={ratingIcon}
                      activeOpacity={rateFunction ? 0.3 : 1}
                      onPress={() => rateFunction(index)}>
                      {Icons.Generator.Awesome(
                        "star",
                        rateFunction ? width * 0.09 : 12,
                        rate ? DCColor.BGColor("primary-1") : DCColor.BGColor("disable"),
                      )}
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  ))}
              </View>
            )}
```

Everything look fine but i hard to understand with `rateFunction`

Note that **this function not pass from anywhere, not a defined function above, just use only on this the code i provide**, and it only use on this file

So it that `rateFunction ? 0.3 : 1` mean that it will be **0.3 when we press** and **1 when not**, or in another way, rateFunction will be **true** if we press???
I never see this type of this before in react

Comment: rateFunction has to be defined somewhere otherwise there is a undefined variable error here

Comment: Problem is, it never use, for whole project, so weird

Comment: This is another question but can you show me what it is initialized to?

`rateFunction ? 0.3 : 1` will give you 0.3 if rateFunction is evaluate to truth value
all value that is not undefined, null, 0 etc will give you 0.3

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#:~:text=The%20conditional%20(ternary)%20operator%20is,if%20the%20condition%20is%20falsy.

Comment: But problem is, it just use in these piece of code, i also think it will be undefine

Comment: Then it is undefined and always giving you 1, (PS: should use typescript as this kind of error would immediately shows up)

Comment: The problem come from firebase console, it show undefined not a function, sure, it have that, BUT, it only affect small of user

Comment: ternary operator is basically an if-else statement, in your code if rateFunction is truthy then `0.3` is the returned value

Comment: So weird because it still have value, but if it undefined, it will throw error when we press right?

Comment: No javascript won't throw an error on undefined

Comment: Did you log it to see what is it?

Comment: It will just evaluate the ternary and always give you 1

Comment: @Fauzanadhim thank for reply , but my question is about ``rateFunction``, it not defined anywhere, how can it still can be used ?

Comment: Javascript allows you lots of weird stuff, if you were to use typescript this kind or error would actually trigger an error, javascript here might assumes it has a value undefined, and therefore (undefined being a Falsy value) it evaluate the ternary to return you `1`

Comment: @VincentRouilhac it must be underfined, right? But do it have value ``true`` when we press?

Comment: Swear i never see this type of syntax

Comment: No here it doesn't

Comment: @VincentRouilhac but why we have type of syntax, the magic is, it not getting error

Comment: Your best bet here is to use `useState` naming it rateFunction, and set it to false, then on `onPress` function use `setRateFunction(true)` to make it change on press

Comment: @CODEforDREAM react wouldn't be able to compile if it is not defined anywhere,

Comment: @VincentRouilhac , no this code from existed project, i mean, it run and work, just trying to understand what going on, my knowledge know that rateFunction will be undefined when press, but it not, that problem 

Comment: @Fauzanadhim Hmm so weird

Comment: might need more context here xD because to me the cause should trigger an undefined error

Comment: @VincentRouilhac i'm think exactly like you , as my experience it must be undefined , i never see this before

Comment: Is this function imported?

Comment: No @DavidScholz, that weird thing, actually it imported as props, BUT it only appear in this file, i search whole project with keyword rateFunction